# Template try to display data that not received from server

Tags: angular, typescript

I use angular 10 for my project.

In OnInit function I make http call to fetch data from server and put it to the class property which is called desc:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.myService.getData(id).subscribe(response => {this.desc = response.results })
    
  }
```

Here is how desc is declared in the component:

```
desc: Desc;
```

Here is Desc definition:

```
    export interface Desc {
        codeName: string;
        mapId: string;
        roster: string;
    }
```

In the template I show the codeName prioperty of the desc that was recieved from server:

```
  <div class="level-left">
        <h1 class="has-text-info"> Your Code: {{ desc.codeName}} </h1>
   </div>
```

But when the component is loaded I get this error:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeName' of undefined
```

It seems that DOM try to access and show the codeName value of desc variable before the data is recived from the server.
I know that to prevent this situation I can use ngIf directive to check that desc variable is not null,
but does it a good approch to use ngIf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngIf is a bad choice because that will hide your html till the response comes and you don't want to have a hidden html in case of error for example. You can try using safe **navigation ?**

```
<h1 class="has-text-info"> Your Code: {{ desc?.codeName}} </h1>
```

and it's possible to use async pipe if you want, no need to subscribe and unsubscribe

```
desc: Observable<Desc>;
this.desc = this.myService.getData(id).pipe(map(data => data.results));
```

...

```
<h1 class="has-text-info"> Your Code: {{ (desc | async)?.codeName}} </h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for the post, how do you think is it good idea to create the service that will be related to the component and to move the myService to the created service and to trigger it before I load the described component above? This component is child componen, so I can call myService  from the parent component.

Comment: ok this is another topic, well if it's a child component better you use it as a presentation component, just to display data. you can pass data to it through input and don't forget to use changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush for performance